# How to get String response from JSONObject in Volley

Tags: android, android-layout, httprequest, android-volley, android-json

I have created JSONRequest by using volley, It successfully hits the service, I checked the service end, It receives the data, and send "Success" in return.

The problem is that, Service returns `String` in output, and Volley excepts some `JSON Data` in output. So it executes  the `onError` Method, instead of `onResponse`.

Kindly guide me how to make it accept string response, or is it not possible when you are using `JSONObject`as request.

```
    Request<JSONObject> jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://192.168.0.101:8888/api/services/mytest",
            jsonParent, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("Success", response.toString());
            deleteFile();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Error", error.toString());
            deleteFile();
        }

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: either use string request or send string in a jsonobject

Comment: It depends what server is returning if only String use StringRequest if you getting JSON value simple use JSONObject/ArrayRequest

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use StringRequest instead JSONRequest.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(methodType, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }){
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    return headers == null ? super.getHeaders() : headers;
                }

                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                    return "Your JSON body".toString().getBytes();
                }
            };
```

`getheaders` method is to add custom headers if you want and `getBody` to supply `request body`.

Comment: but i need to add JSON object in Body of request, and  that looks possible only through JSONObject request

Comment: No you can do that with this as well, let me update the answer

Comment: @NayanSrivastava did update the answer.  It's getBody() the one converts the JSON object a string.

Answer (score 6):

**For those who still need to send raw Json and receive a String as response:**

By default, the body consists of the request parameters in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` format for `StringRequest`. When overriding `getBody()`, as Nayan suggested correctly, consider overriding `getBodyContentType()` as well to match the new body format. For Json it should be 
`application/json`.

```
String url = "www.google.com";

HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("key1", "Android");
params.put("isCool", true);

StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, 
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            public void onResponse(String response) {

            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }
    ) {
        public byte[] getBody() {
            return new JSONObject(params).toString().getBytes();
        }
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json";
        }
    };

Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);
```